# Can I add a new line in tooltip? google charts

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Here I have array with tooltip

```
<script>
<?php
echo'
['$compname', '$dancerName placed $dancer_placed out of $competitors 
Dance Name: $dance Comp Name: $feis Date: $date', '$dancer_placed'],
'
?>
</script>
```

on the tooltip I want it to show up like this:

```
Lace place 14 out of 45
Dance Name: Boogie
Comp Name: New Jersey Light Worlds 2018
Date: Jan/1/2018
```

But it is showing up like this

```
Lace place 14 out of 45
Dance Name: Boogie Comp 
Name: New Jersey Light 
Worlds 2018 Date: Jan
/1/2018
```

Is there anyway to have a line break?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
    echo "
['$compname', '$dancerName placed $dancer_placed out of $competitors \n
Dance Name: $dance Comp \n Name: $feis \nDate: $date', '$dancer_placed'],
"
```

or `echo "
[\"$compname\", \"$dancerName placed $dancer_placed out of $competitors \n
Dance Name: $dance Comp \n Name: $feis \nDate: $date\", \"$dancer_placed\"],
"`

Comment: I thought it might work.. But when I include the \n the chart stopped drawing.